# What is the error when it says " Error in ROI: L_constraint........."?

Tags: r, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

I am trying to learn portfolio optimization. However, I cannot get past this error. Could anybody please tell me a way to fix this?

Here is my code:

#calculate returns of all the stocks in our portfolio

```
portfolioROC<- na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrices))
head(portfolioROC)
```

#Now, weighted returns of our portfolio of stocks

```
portfolioReturns<- Return.portfolio(portfolioROC)
head(portfolioReturns)
tail(portfolioReturns)
```

#Now, start optimizing out portfolio. In order to do that, we shall now start adding constraints and
#specifications to our portfolios

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
```

#Initializing our portfolio object

```
portf<- portfolio.spec(colnames(portfolioReturns))
```

#Now, passing some constraints

#constraint 1

```
portf<- add.constraint(portf, type="weight_sum", min_sum=1,
                       max_sum=1)
```

#Constraint 2

#type "box" is asking how much capital to allocate to each individual stocks

```
portf<- add.constraint(portf,type="box",min=0.10, max=0.4)
```

#Now, adding objectives for the portfolio

```
portf<-add.objective(portf, type="return", name="mean")
portf<-add.objective(portf,type="risk", name="StdDev")
```

#Now, we gonna have to use a solver to basically solve for these weights
#Note that there different solvers that you can use. In this case we are gonna use "ROI",

```
library(ROI.plugin.quadprog)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ROI)

optPort<- optimize.portfolio(portfolioReturns,
                             portf,
                             optimize_method = "ROI")
```

I am having a problem in this very last part of the code. It shows this error:

```
Error in ROI::L_constraint(L = Amat, dir = dir.vec, rhs = rhs.vec) : 
  all(c(dim_L[1], n_dir) == n_L_constraints) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have actually installed the packages specified.

`install.packages(c("ROI","ROI.plugin.glpk","ROI.plugin.quadprog"))`

If the installation for the glpk plugin does not work, follow the tutorial specified [here](https://roi.r-forge.r-project.org/installation.html).

Also ensure that the dimension of your `portfolioReturns` object is correct.